# Solve first 1st order differential dV/dt=S-CV^1/2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I am trying to solve the following first order differential equation:

$\frac{dV}{dt} = S-CV^\frac{1}{2}$

I can't see how this could be solved via separation of variables or integrating factor as it is not linear.

I don't know if I'm missing something, is there a straight forward way of solving this?

Comment: Use $W=\sqrt{V}$ then $$Cdt=\frac{2CWdW}{S-CW}=-2dW+2\frac{SdW}{S-CW}$$ hence $$Ct=-2W-2\frac{S}C\log|S-CW|+c$$ that is, $$|S-CW|^Se^{CW}=ce^{-C^2t/2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$\dfrac{dV}{dt} = S-CV^\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\dfrac{dV}{S-CV^\frac{1}{2}} = dt$$

The integral on the right side is equal to:

$$ -\frac{2 (S \log(S-C \sqrt{V})+C \sqrt{V})}{C^2}+c$$

Answer (score 1):

let 
$$V^{\frac{1}{2}}=u$$
derive both sides respect to $t$
$$\frac{1}{2}V^{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{du}{dt}$$
$$\frac{1}{2u}\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{du}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=2u\frac{du}{dt}$$
substitute it
$$2u\frac{du}{dt}=S-Cu$$
$$\frac{2udu}{S-Cu}=dt$$
$$-\frac{2du}{C}+\frac{2Sdu}{C(S-Cu)}=dt$$